# Manual hover function in javascript

Tags: javascript, hover

I do not know what is wrong, but the hover function as I wrote it here stays even when I am not hovering the button. I know that there is simpler way to hover an object, but I am learning the basics, so it would be helpful to get what is wrong with this exact code that I have.

```
<head>
  <style>
    .tabStrip {
      background-color: #E4E2D5;
      padding: 15px;
      height: 22px;
      width: 130px;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .tabStrip div {
      float: left;
      font: 14px arial;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .tabStrip-tab {
      padding: 5px;
    }

    .tabStrip-tab-hover {
      border: 1px solid #316AC5;
      background-color: #C1D2EE;
      padding: 4px;
    }

    .tabStrip-tab-click {
      border: 1px solid #facc5a;
      background-color: #f9e391;
      padding: 4px;
    }
  </style>

</head>


<body>

  <div class="tabStrip">
    <div data-tab-number="1" class="tabStrip-tab">Tab1</div>
    <div data-tab-number="2" class="tabStrip-tab">Tab2</div>
    <div data-tab-number="3" class="tabStrip-tab">Tab3</div>
  </div>

  <div id="descContainer"></div>

  <script>
    function handleEvent(e) {
      var target = e.target;
      switch (e.type) {
        case 'mouseover':
          if (target.className == 'tabStrip-tab') {
            target.className = 'tabStrip-tab-hover';
          }
          break;
        case 'mouseout':
          if (targer.className == 'tabStrip-tab-hover') {
            targer.className = 'tabStrip-tab';
          }
          break;
        case 'click':
          if (target.className == 'tabStrip-tab-hover') {
            target.className = 'tabStrip-tab-click';
            var num = target.getAttribute('data-tab-number');
            showDescription(num);
          }
          break;
      }
    }

    function showDescription(num) {
      var descContainer = document.getElementById('descContainer')
      var text = 'description for tab ' + num;
      descContainer.innerHTML = text;
    }

    document.addEventListener('mouseover', handleEvent);
    document.addEventListener('mouseout', handleEvent);
    document.addEventListener('click', handleEvent);
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be you misspelled target as targer in your javascript

Correct:

```
function handleEvent(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  switch (e.type) {
    case 'mouseover':
      if (target.className == 'tabStrip-tab') {
        target.className = 'tabStrip-tab-hover';
      }
      break;
    case 'mouseout':
      if (target.className == 'tabStrip-tab-hover') {
        target.className = 'tabStrip-tab';
      }
      break;
    case 'click':
      if (target.className == 'tabStrip-tab-hover') {
        target.className = 'tabStrip-tab-click';
        var num = target.getAttribute('data-tab-number');
        showDescription(num);
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

[Codepen of it working correctly](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/WrJQQP)

Answer (score 0):

Your spelling is incorrect in the mouseout event. It is `targer` instead of `target.

```
case 'mouseout':
    if (target.className == 'tabStrip-tab-hover') {
        target.className = 'tabStrip-tab';
    }
    break;
```